# Flutter - Why am I only seeing a white container instead of a native banner test ad on my iOS device?

Tags: flutter, facebook-audience-network

I'm implementing the Facebook Audience Network in my Flutter app. I have implemented Native Banner Ad. However, when i run on iOS device I'm getting a white blank container instead of a test ad.

This issue has been occurring for the past two days, while previously it was working properly.

[image]